# AWS EC2:NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, deployment, object-detection

So I am deploying an OCR model specifically detectron2 on AWS ec2 instance. But the detectron2 started giving an error for GPU. So when I run the command nvidia-smi in the ec2 terminal it shows the error as in title.

Note: I have chosen the Deep Learning PyTorch AMI with CUDA already enabled.

I need GPU to run my model but as it is not detecting it is failing. I had tried this same thing before a month to check if it runs and it worked perfectly but now suddenly all the AMI's with CUDA has started giving this errors.

Comment: Does your virtual machine have a GPU, and if yes, are GPU drivers correctly installed?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes the VM comes with GPU and drivers pre-installed

Comment: @AnonCoward t2. I had used the t2.large a month before and everything worked like charm. But now nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a DLAMI with a non GPU instance. As t2.large does not have nvidia GPU. Your best bet is to either use G4dn.xlarge or G4g.xlarge.

But i would recommend you not to waste energies on market place available AMIs instead use a base Linux image and install only the necessary drivers on top of it. I wrote a guide on [how to create custom deep learning AMI](https://mirzabilal.com/deep-learning-with-aws-graviton2-nvidia-tensor-t4g-for-as-low-as-free-with-cuda-12-2-56d8457a6f6d) but if you only need driver you can skip the guide or follow the GPU drive installation process mentioned [here](https://mirzabilal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-with-harware-accelaration-on-aws).

Specifically this part

```bash
if [ "$(uname -m)" = "aarch64" ]; then
    echo "System is running on ARM / AArch64"
    DRIVE_URL="https://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/535.104.05/NVIDIA-Linux-aarch64-535.104.05.run"
    CUDA_SDK_URL="https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.2/local_installers/cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux_sbsa.run"
    CUDNN_ARCHIVE_URL="https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/redist/cudnn/linux-sbsa/cudnn-linux-sbsa-8.9.5.29_cuda12-archive.tar.xz"
else
    DRIVE_URL="https://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/535.104.05/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.104.05.run"
    CUDA_SDK_URL="https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.2/local_installers/cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux.run"
    CUDNN_ARCHIVE_URL="https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/redist/cudnn/linux-x86_64/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.9.5.29_cuda12-archive.tar.xz"
fi
echo "Setting up GPU..."
DRIVER_NAME="NVIDIA-Linux-driver.run"
wget -O "$DRIVER_NAME" "$DRIVE_URL"
TMPDIR=$LOCAL_TMP sh "$DRIVER_NAME" --disable-nouveau --silent

CUDA_SDK="cuda-linux.run"
wget -O "$CUDA_SDK" "$CUDA_SDK_URL"
TMPDIR=$LOCAL_TMP sh "$CUDA_SDK" --silent --override --toolkit --samples --toolkitpath=$USR_LOCAL_PREFIX/cuda-12.2 --samplespath=$CUDA_HOME --no-opengl-libs

CUDNN_ARCHIVE="cudnn-linux.tar.xz"
EXTRACT_PATH="$SRC_DIR/cudnn-extracted"
mkdir -p "$EXTRACT_PATH"

wget -O "$CUDNN_ARCHIVE" "$CUDNN_ARCHIVE_URL"
tar -xJf "$CUDNN_ARCHIVE" -C "$EXTRACT_PATH"
CUDNN_INCLUDE=$(find "$EXTRACT_PATH" -type d -name "include" -print -quit)
CUDNN_LIB=$(find "$EXTRACT_PATH" -type d -name "lib" -print -quit)
cp -P "$CUDNN_INCLUDE"/* $CUDA_HOME/include/
cp -P "$CUDNN_LIB"/* $CUDA_HOME/lib64/
chmod a+r $CUDA_HOME/lib64/*
ldconfig
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of these articles where i mentioned in detail how to setup GPU in the cloud.